# MongoDB Full-TextSearch C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I have a text index on a specific field, rather than the wild card text index.  The C# driver doesn't seem to have a parameter to pass a field name though:

```
public FilterDefinition<TDocument> Text(string search, TextSearchOptions options = null);
```

How do I tell Mongo what field I want to search?

Comment: Text indexes "define" the fields in which to search and not the search condition. There can only be one text index on a collection, therefore that is why there is no option to specify a field. Not a driver issue, but just how text searching works. See the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator.

Comment: please read the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915209/mongodb-net-driver-and-text-search/48677313#48677313

Comment: @TolgaKabadurmus These are different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blakes mentioned, MongoDB can have only one full text index per collection so you don't need to tell which field to search. MongoDB knows where to search.

It will search whatever field is included in text index. However if you want complete control, you can use $regex and don't use full text search.