# MongoDB .NET driver and text search

Tags: mongodb, linq

I am using this MongoDB driver: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/
and I would like to search using a text index, which (I think) is created on all text fields like so:

```
{
    "_fts" : "text",
    "_ftsx" : 1
}
```

I am using linq queries to filter the data, example:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(_mongoConnectionString);
IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
var aCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<MyTypeSerializable>(CollectionName);

IMongoQueryable<MyTypeSerializable> queryable = aCollection.AsQueryable()
                .Where(e=> e.Field == 1);
var result = queryable.ToList();
```

How do I utilize the text search using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `PredicateTranslator` within the C# MongoDB driver there isn't any expression that gets converted in to a `text` query. So you won't be able to achive a `text` query using a linq query.

- [PredicateTranslator.cs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/ee797128a1a3a78bb7b492b78f93d2d85b96f738/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs)
- [PredicateTranslatorTests.cs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/ee797128a1a3a78bb7b492b78f93d2d85b96f738/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslatorTests.cs)

However you could try just doing a text search with the `Builder<>`:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(_mongoConnectionString);
IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
var aCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<MyTypeSerializable>(CollectionName);

var cursor = await aCollection.FindAsync(Builders<MyTypeSerializable>.Filter.Text("search"));

var results = await cursor.ToListAsync();
```

Details about the text filter is here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: Looks legit, I'll check it out and come back, thank you.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to combine this approach with linq-based filters? Can I do `cursor.ToEnumerable().Where(e => e.Field == 1)` and it will actually get "materialized" after a `.ToList()` at the end?

Comment: Not sure you can mix and match Linq with Mongo Filters, try: `var builder = Builders<MyModel>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.And(
                builder.Text("search"),
                builder.Eq(x => x.Field, 1)
                );`

Answer (score 14):

Searching for solution I found [`FilterDefinition<T>.Inject()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/LinqExtensions.cs) extension method.
So we can go deeper and create one more extension on `IMongoQueryable<T>`:

```cs
public static class MongoQueryableFullTextExtensions
{
    public static IMongoQueryable<T> WhereText<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> query, string search)
    {
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Text(search);
        return query.Where(_ => filter.Inject());
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
IMongoDatabase database = GetMyDatabase();

var results = database
    .GetCollection<Blog>("Blogs")
    .AsQueryable()
    .WhereText("stackoverflow")
    .Take(10)
    .ToArray();
```

Hope this helps somebody :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! The same method (using a builder then injecting into a `where` call) also allows you constructing any other query like geo-spatial queries etc.

Comment: Holy crap man this is awesome! I was literally trying to juggle keeping a reference to the mongocollection in my repository only for doing text searches.  Now I can just keep the IMongoQueryable reference and keep on trucking.

Comment: I know is 4 years before, but thanks man this is awesome

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to modify MongoDb driver source code. Let me explain it to you:

1. Consider "PredicateTranslator" does not convert linq Expression into "$text" query. However there is a Text() method "FilterDefinitionBuilder" class, "PredicateTranslator" does not know the entity class property has a text search index.
2. You have to mark entity class property (a condition in predicate statement) with an Attribute. The attribute works to remark property has a full text search index.
3. From now on "PredicateTranslator" class knows the property has a full text search index with this Attribute "PredicateTranslator"

Let me show you some code:

1. At MongoDB.Bson project create an Attribute as shown below:

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
   public class BsonFullTextSearchAttribute : Attribute
   {
   }
2. At your entity class property place the "BsonFullTextSearchAttribute" Attribute as shown below:

   ```
   public class History 
   {
       [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonFullTextSearch]
       public string ObjectJSON { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. At MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.cs

   - Add a field that keeps entity class type in Expression>, as shown below:

     ```
     private Type _sourceObjectTypeInExpression;
     ```
   - Add a method to get entity class type as shown below:

     ```
     private void GetObjectType(Expression node)
     {
         if (node.Type != null && node.Type.GenericTypeArguments != null && node.Type.GenericTypeArguments.Length > 0)
         {
             this._sourceObjectTypeInExpression = node.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0]; 
         }
      }
     ```
   - Replace "public static QueryableTranslation Translate()" method as shown below:

     ```
     public static QueryableTranslation Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)
     {
     var translator = new QueryableTranslator(serializerRegistry, translationOptions);
     translator.GetObjectType(node);
     translator.Translate(node);

     var outputType = translator._outputSerializer.ValueType;
     var modelType = typeof(AggregateQueryableExecutionModel<>).MakeGenericType(outputType);
     var modelTypeInfo = modelType.GetTypeInfo();
     var outputSerializerInterfaceType = typeof(IBsonSerializer<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { outputType });
     var constructorParameterTypes = new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<BsonDocument>), outputSerializerInterfaceType };
     var constructorInfo = modelTypeInfo.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
         .Where(c => c.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(constructorParameterTypes))
         .Single();
     var constructorParameters = new object[] { translator._stages, translator._outputSerializer };
     var model = (QueryableExecutionModel)constructorInfo.Invoke(constructorParameters);

     return new QueryableTranslation(model, translator._resultTransformer);
     }
     ```
   - In TranslateWhere() method pass "_sourceObjectTypeInExpression" field to PredicateTranslator.Translate() static method

     ```
     var predicateValue = PredicateTranslator.Translate(node.Predicate, _serializerRegistry, this._sourceObjectTypeInExpression);
     ```

     B. MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.cs
         - Add a field: "private Type sourceObjectTypeInExpression = null;"

     ```
     - Replace constructor as shown below (there has to be only one constructor);
         private PredicateTranslator(Type _sourceObjectTypeInExpression)
         {
             this.sourceObjectTypeInExpression = _sourceObjectTypeInExpression;
         }

     - Replace function "public static BsonDocument Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)" as shown below;
         public static BsonDocument Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, Type sourceObjectTypeInExpression)
         {
             var translator = new PredicateTranslator(sourceObjectTypeInExpression);
             node = FieldExpressionFlattener.FlattenFields(node);
             return translator.Translate(node)
                 .Render(serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>(), serializerRegistry);
         }

     - Add these lines for reflection cache:
         #region FullTextSearch
         private static readonly object mSysncFullTextSearchObjectCache = new object();
         private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _fullTextSearchObjectCache = null;
         private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> FullTextSearchObjectCache
         {
             get
             {
                 if (_fullTextSearchObjectCache == null)
                 {
                     lock (mSysncFullTextSearchObjectCache)
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             if (_fullTextSearchObjectCache == null)
                             {
                                 _fullTextSearchObjectCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
                             }
                         }
                         finally
                         {
                             Monitor.PulseAll(mSysncFullTextSearchObjectCache);
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 return _fullTextSearchObjectCache;
             }
         }

         private bool IsFullTextSearchProp(Type entityType, string propName)
         {
             bool retVal = false;
             string entityName = entityType.Name;

             this.SetObject2FullTextSearchObjectCache(entityType);
             if (FullTextSearchObjectCache.ContainsKey(entityName))
             {
                 List<string> x = FullTextSearchObjectCache[entityName];
                 retVal = x.Any(p => p == propName);
             }

             return retVal;
         }

         private void SetObject2FullTextSearchObjectCache(Type entityType)
         {
             string entityName = entityType.Name;

             if (!FullTextSearchObjectCache.ContainsKey(entityName))
             {
                 List<string> retVal = new List<string>();

                 PropertyInfo[] currentProperties = entityType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                 foreach (PropertyInfo tmp in currentProperties)
                 {
                     var attributes = tmp.GetCustomAttributes();
                     BsonFullTextSearchAttribute x = (BsonFullTextSearchAttribute)attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => typeof(BsonFullTextSearchAttribute) == a.GetType());
                     if (x != null)
                     {
                         retVal.Add(tmp.Name);
                     }
                 }

                 FieldInfo[] currentFields = entityType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                 foreach (FieldInfo tmp in currentFields)
                 {
                     var attributes = tmp.GetCustomAttributes();
                     BsonFullTextSearchAttribute x = (BsonFullTextSearchAttribute)attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => typeof(BsonFullTextSearchAttribute) == a.GetType());
                     if (x != null)
                     {
                         retVal.Add(tmp.Name);
                     }
                 }

                 FullTextSearchObjectCache.AddOrUpdate(entityName, retVal, (k, v) => v);
             }
         }
         #endregion

     - Replace "switch (operatorType)" switch in "private FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)" function as shown below;
         bool isFullTextSearchProp = this.IsFullTextSearchProp(this.sourceObjectTypeInExpression, fieldExpression.FieldName);
         switch (operatorType)
         {
             case ExpressionType.Equal:
                 if (!isFullTextSearchProp)
                 {
                     return __builder.Eq(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return __builder.Text(serializedValue.ToString());
                 }
             case ExpressionType.GreaterThan: return __builder.Gt(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
             case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual: return __builder.Gte(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
             case ExpressionType.LessThan: return __builder.Lt(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
             case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual: return __builder.Lte(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
             case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                 if (!isFullTextSearchProp)
                 {
                     return __builder.Ne(fieldExpression.FieldName, serializedValue);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Cannot use \"NotEqual\" on FullTextSearch property: \"{0}\"", fieldExpression.FieldName));
                 }
         }

     - Replace "switch (methodCallExpression.Method.Name)" switch in "private FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> TranslateStringQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)" function as shown below;
         bool isFullTextSearchProp = this.IsFullTextSearchProp(this.sourceObjectTypeInExpression, tmpFieldExpression.FieldName);
         var pattern = Regex.Escape((string)constantExpression.Value);
         if (!isFullTextSearchProp)
         {
             switch (methodCallExpression.Method.Name)
             {
                 case "Contains": pattern = ".*" + pattern + ".*"; break;
                 case "EndsWith": pattern = ".*" + pattern; break;
                 case "StartsWith": pattern = pattern + ".*"; break; // query optimizer will use index for rooted regular expressions
                 default: return null;
             }

             var caseInsensitive = false;
             MethodCallExpression stringMethodCallExpression;
             while ((stringMethodCallExpression = stringExpression as MethodCallExpression) != null)
             {
                 var trimStart = false;
                 var trimEnd = false;
                 Expression trimCharsExpression = null;
                 switch (stringMethodCallExpression.Method.Name)
                 {
                     case "ToLower":
                     case "ToLowerInvariant":
                     case "ToUpper":
                     case "ToUpperInvariant":
                         caseInsensitive = true;
                         break;
                     case "Trim":
                         trimStart = true;
                         trimEnd = true;
                         trimCharsExpression = stringMethodCallExpression.Arguments.FirstOrDefault();
                         break;
                     case "TrimEnd":
                         trimEnd = true;
                         trimCharsExpression = stringMethodCallExpression.Arguments.First();
                         break;
                     case "TrimStart":
                         trimStart = true;
                         trimCharsExpression = stringMethodCallExpression.Arguments.First();
                         break;
                     default:
                         return null;
                 }

                 if (trimStart || trimEnd)
                 {
                     var trimCharsPattern = GetTrimCharsPattern(trimCharsExpression);
                     if (trimCharsPattern == null)
                     {
                         return null;
                     }

                     if (trimStart)
                     {
                         pattern = trimCharsPattern + pattern;
                     }
                     if (trimEnd)
                     {
                         pattern = pattern + trimCharsPattern;
                     }
                 }

                 stringExpression = stringMethodCallExpression.Object;
             }

             pattern = "^" + pattern + "$";
             if (pattern.StartsWith("^.*"))
             {
                 pattern = pattern.Substring(3);
             }
             if (pattern.EndsWith(".*$"))
             {
                 pattern = pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 3);
             }

             var fieldExpression = GetFieldExpression(stringExpression);
             var options = caseInsensitive ? "is" : "s";
             return __builder.Regex(fieldExpression.FieldName, new BsonRegularExpression(pattern, options));
         }
         else
         {
             return __builder.Text(pattern);
         }
     ```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
IMongoQueryable<MyTypeSerializable> queryable = aCollection
.AsQueryable()
.Where(e=> e.Field.Contains("term"));
```

Comment: Are you sure this utilizes the text index?

Comment: It depends on 2 factors: implementation of Linq provider and query processor on mongodb side. In order to be sure you have to trace this chain.

Comment: Looking though the source code the above doesn't utilise the text query within mongodb.